# Does a car constitute land ownership for pruzbul?

Tags: shmita, pruzbul

What are the rules regarding land ownership for a pruzbul? 
 Yad Avraham in Uktzin 3:10 quotes a gemara in Bava Basra stating that for a pruzbul to be effective the debtor (one who owes money) must be a landowner.
 Would a car make someone a landowner in this context?

Comment: How would a car make someone a land owner in any context?

Comment: @DoubleAA Seems to be a confusion with *hilchos tumah ve'taharah*.

Comment: @pcoz Or maybe on the theory that it could be car-ka.

Comment: @pcoz is a car tahor?

Comment: @Heshy https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%98%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%AA_%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%99_%D7%A2%D7%A5 חכמים שיערו, שכלי המכיל יותר מארבעים סאה נוזל לח, אינו מטלטל כאשר הוא מלא ואינו מקבל טומאה.

Comment: @pcoz that's if it's wood

Comment: @Heshy Understood, that was the nearest confusion I could think of.

Comment: I believe there's a mishna in keilim which mentions a boat... wonder if they would be the same

Comment: @heshy 
_"...Rabbi Judah says: the tub of a wagon, the food chests of kings, the tanners trough, the tank of a small ship, and an ark, even though they are able to contain the minimum, are susceptible to impurity, since they are intended to be moved about with their contents..."_
https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Kelim.15.1 (there's also a wagon mentioned here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gemara in [Gittin 37a](https://www.sefaria.org/Gittin.37a.3?lang=bi) answers your question (translation R Steinsaltz) that one needs a very small amount of land and it can even be lent to the debtor.

> We learned in a mishna there (Shevi’it 10:6): **One may write a prosbol
> only on the basis of the debtor owning land. If the debtor has no
> land, then the creditor transfers any amount of his own field to him
> so that he can write a prosbol.** The Gemara asks: **And how much is
> sufficient to be classified as any amount? Rav Ḥiyya bar Ashi says
> that Rav says: Even the amount of land sufficient to grow a stalk of
> cabbage is sufficient.** Rav Yehuda says: Even if he lent him a place
> sufficient for an oven and a stove, one may write a prosbol on this
> basis.

This is codified by the Rambam [MT Shviit 9:19](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Sabbatical_Year_and_the_Jubilee.9.19?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

Since a car is not land, it cannot serve as a basis for a *prozbul*. But one who doesn't own land is commonly lent the amount required (see e.g., [instructions from the OU](https://www.crcweb.org/audios/R_Yona_Reiss/YReiss-2015-07-17_Pruzbul_Forms.pdf), p. 2, point 5).

Note also the a *prozbul* is only written at the **end** of the seventh year, since debits acquired it is written are not prescribed ([MT 9:22](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Sabbatical_Year_and_the_Jubilee.9.22?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

Comment: "a prozbul is only written at the end of the seventh year" This is subject to some dispute, though this is the most common practice